# .htaccess redirect from directory it's in to specific subdirectory without filename

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have a server. (Apache).

On this server there is a subdirectory (subdir1). In this subdirectory, I have an .htaccess file. How can I set up this .htaccess file to redirect me from the directory it is in (regardless of what the directory is called) to a specific subdirectory?

```
Redirect {current .htaccess directory} {current .htaccess direcotry}/subdir2/subdir3
```

Or something like that?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure you want a redirect? If you redirect from `/subdir1` to `/subdir1/subdir2`, you are still inside `/subdir1`, so quite clearly you'll get another redirect to `/subdir1/subdir2/subdir2`, then `/subdir1/subdir2/subdir2/subdir2`, and so on until the browser gives up. (As you say in your comment to Sacx's answer.)

If you want to redirect into `/subdir1/subdir2`, you'll have to exclude `subdir2` from matching the redirect, for example something like:

```
RedirectMatch permanent /subdir1(?!/subdir2)(.*)$ http://www.example.com/subdir1/subdir2$1
```

this is pretty ugly though. It's unusual to want to do a redirect from a directory to a subdirectory of itself. Are you sure you really want a redirect? If you just want to make files physically located under `/subdir1/subdir2/file` look visible as `/subdir1/file`, I think what you'd want would really be an [Alias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#alias):

```
Alias /subdir1 /home/wwwuser/examplesite/htdocs/subdir1/subdir2
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use RedirectPermanent.

RedirectPermanent /cur_dirr/ /curr_dirr/subdir2/subdir3

Comment: Well, then I am redirected to /cur_dirr/subdir2/subdir3subdir2/subdir3subdir2/subdir3... and I get a browser error of having been redirected too often. Plus, this is not regardless of the directory name.